# C++ Exception Handling between Classes

Tags: c++, exception

I'm working on exception handling and right now I'm stuck on a problem I'm working on out of my book. What I'm trying to do is add an try-catch block inside my main function to catch an exception that is thrown by a function that I am using. Here are snippets of where I am having trouble on.

`EmptyStackPopException` is an empty Exception class that I put into my `stack.h` file that can be seen here:

```
class EmptyStackPopException {
    };
```

Here is the function that is supposed to throw this Exception.

```
T Stack<T>::pop( ) throw (EmptyStackPopException)
    {
        if (isEmpty( ))
        {
        throw EmptyStackPopException();
        }

        T result = top->getData( );

        Node<T> *discard;
        discard = top;
        top = top->getLink( );

        delete discard;

        return result;
    }
```

Here is a snippet of my main function where the exception is supposed to be caught:

```
try {
    cout << s.pop( );
} catch (EmptyStackPopException) {
    cout << "EmptyStackPopException: You didn't enter anything in." << endl;
        }
```

Now the issue that I'm having is I cannot compile because of these following errors:

```
..\assignment8\main.cpp(29) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'EmptyStackPopException'
..\assignment8\main.cpp(29) : error C2310: catch handlers must specify one type
..\assignment8\main.cpp(32) : error C2317: 'try' block starting on line '27' has no catch handlers
```

I'm pretty sure that the only error I have at the moment is in the main function, EmptyStackPopException is not able to be detected in the client program which causes the last two errors.

Comment: Your error messages don't correspond to the code you posted. Probably there is a typo in your code somewhere which you didn't reproduce in your question. It would help greatly if you took the time to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a type with your catch statement.  This should fix the three syntax errors your presented

```
try {
    cout << s.pop( );
} catch (EmptyStackPopException& exception) {
    cout << "EmptyStackPopException: You didn't enter anything in." << endl;
}
```

You needed to create 'exception'.

If including your EmptyStackPopException header doesn't work (based on context I'm not sure it will), the problem might be based on circular dependency, which means that two header files are including each other.  I can't tell from context but this sometimes gives me the "syntax error : identifier" error.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not seem to fix it. Am I missing an include or something?

Comment: Did you include your EmptyStackPopException class?